# Replace words that don't start with certain prefix using sed

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I want to replace every instance of `word` that doesn't have the prefix `pre`, with `preword` using `sed`. So the `word` in `preword` should not be replaced, but a lone `word` should be replaced with `preword`.

I tried the usual negative look-behind regex like so

`sed -E -i 's/(?<!pre)word/preword/g'`

but it gives me the error

`sed: -e expression #1, char 22: Invalid preceding regular expression`

I've read that GNU `sed` has some different ways of treating regex. What can I do to get this done?

Comment: Should `foreword` become `forepreword`? Clarify your requirements and show concise, testable sample input and expected output that covers all of your use cases.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to avoid "word" with "pre" before, match the "pre" too and replace it systematically:

```
sed -E 's/(pre)?word/preword/g'
```

Other way (more general), you put in a capture group all that isn't "pre":

```
sed -E 's/(^|[^e]|^e|[^r]e|^re|[^p]re)word/\1preword/g'
```

Answer (score 2):

With GNU sed:

```
sed 's/\bword\b/preword/g' file
```

> `\b` is a zero-width word boundary

Comment: Disadvantage: It won‘t replace `microsoftword`.

Comment: I see. But my application does actually want to replace only words that have a boundary at the beginning.

Comment: @Cyrus you'll need natural language processing (tokenization) for this, unless you want to replace every `sword` as `spreword` as well.

Comment: Could shorten slightly to `'s/\bword\b/pre&/g'`

Answer (score 1):

If you need a complex regular expression you can also consider 
writing a tiny parser.

```
$ cat r.awk
BEGIN {
    re_wrd = "^[A-Za-z]+" # what we consider a word
    re_sep  = "^."        # the rest is a separator
}

function advance() { # sets `tag' and `tok'; eats a part of `line'
    if      (match(line, re_wrd)) tag = "wrd"
    else if (match(line, re_sep)) tag = "sep"
    tok  = substr(line, 1,          RLENGTH)
    line = substr(line, RLENGTH + 1        )
}

function process_sep() { # copy to output
    ans = ans tok
}

function process_wrd() {
    sub(/^word/, "preword", tok) # replace only at the beginning
    ans = ans tok
}

{
    line = $0; ans = tag = tok = ""
    while (length(line) > 0) {
        advance()
        # uncomment for tracing
        # print tag, "<" tok ">" | "cat 1>&2"
        if      (tag == "sep") process_sep()
        else if (tag == "wrd") process_wrd()
    }
    print ans
}
```

Usage:

```
$ echo 'preword...microsoftword word wordword,word.word-preword' | awk -f r.awk
preword...microsoftword preword prewordword,preword.preword-preword
```

Trace:

```
wrd <preword>
sep <.>
sep <.>
sep <.>
wrd <microsoftword>
sep < >
wrd <word>
sep < >
wrd <wordword>
sep <,>
wrd <word>
sep <.>
wrd <word>
sep <->
wrd <preword>
```

Comment: The usage example with `echo` and backticks would cause an error, wouldn't it?

Comment: @BenjaminW. Fixed. Thanks.